# Network details for 3G network

Tags: android, networking, dns, 3g, gateway

WifiManager in android gives network details for Wifi network. But it is not possible to get network details like Gateway, DNS, for 3G network. Is there a way to obtain such details for mobile connected to 3G network.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

not sure but maybe this could help you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html

note: this method: getActiveNetworkInfo(), return a NetworkInfo object with the info of the active connection on device (3G - Wifi).

Comment: It just gives the type of network and some other details but NOT the IP, Gateway, DNS details. JAVA reflection could be helpful but don't know how this works.

Comment: i don't get how reflection could help you on this, anyway i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945288/get-default-gatway-in-java

Comment: traceroute doesn't work in android.  so getting first hop from traceroute to determine gateway doesn't fit for android

Comment: well, via android i don't think you could get that info, `ifconfig` won't work either since that command need `root` permission, let me know if you find the way to do it. Regards.

Comment: netcfg in adb shell displays ip address. Is there a way to execute the command and parse the output?

Comment: seems like you can run `root` commands http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882248/running-shell-commands-though-java-code-on-android and well if it doesn't work try at least without `su` the `netcfg` command, in that post it's explained how to get the data from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Terminal Emulator and BusyBox, you have ifconfig and ip available.

In the emulator you can use "ip link show" to find out what designation is used for the device.
WLAN is usually : wlan0
Modem etc       : rmnet0

ifconfig wlan0 : show you for example the ip and the netmask .

ip route show  : shows you the routing configuration .

Better description: 
[Network configuration and information](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_10_02.html)