# How to Set Default Gateway,Ip Address and Subnet mask from Java?

Tags: java, networking, ethernet, static-ip-address

I am looking some way to configure my Ethernet card from Java. Is there any way to change Default Gateway,IP address and subnet mask from Java.

Currently I am using [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi)to get the ip address,Mac address and other Hardware info. I also understand that the only way to set these parameters is Java.lang.Runtime Class and using Hardware specific command to set properties from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945288/get-default-gateway-in-java)

I am looking for a cleaner way to do this for Linux, Windows and Mac. I am basically trying to set all this properties from my own application. 
Is there a library or wrapper like OSHI to do execute host specific command?

Comment: As far as I knows you can do some registry hacks on windows using java to change networking parameters.

Comment: If answer is acceptable, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
String str1="192.168.0.201";
String str2="255.255.255.0";
String[] command1 = { "netsh", "interface", "ip", "set", "address",
"name=", "Local Area Connection" ,"source=static", "addr=",str1,
"mask=", str2};
Process pp = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```