# Find network adapter name for ethernet connection

Tags: java, windows, networking

I need to find the adapter name and default gateway for the ethernet adapter used to connect to the internet.

I can get the gateway with `netstat -rn` but I'm having problem with the adapter name.

I'm using java and running a `ipconfig` command for Windows systems and parsing the result. It returns the network adapter names in this format

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : customer.service.provider.lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fb80::7d2b:98aa:506:685%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.65.2.21
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.192.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.65.0.1
```

I can match the default gateway and like to parse the string "Local Area Connection" for it. On English locale, I can look for the word "adapter" and parse the name until ":". Problem is on computers with different locale than English, "adapter" is called something else. How can I reliably obtain the network adapter name?

Comment: I've also tried the API call `NetworkInterface.getName()`, but that returns "eth0" instead of the adapter name

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html): Listing Network Interface Addresses
And use getDisplayName() instand of getName(). See Heer to get the Gateway: [How can I determine the IP of my router/gateway in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930)

Comment: Tried. getDisplayName() returns the description of the adapter, which is model-make. Not the name.

Comment: actually, according to the tutorial, it should return the adapter name, but on my machine it doesn't. strange.