# java : regular expression for ipconfig

Tags: java, regex, ipconfig

**Is the output of ipconfig same in all windows machine ??**. I want to capture ip-address , default gateway, subnet mask from ipconfig's output.

Currently i am doing this :

```
String[] arr = s.split("IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ");
            ipAddress = (arr[1].split("\\n"))[0];
            String[] arr1 = s.split("Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : ");
            subnetMask = (arr1[1].split("\\n"))[0];
            String[] arr2 = s.split("Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ");
            defaultGateway = (arr2[1].split("\\n"))[0];
```

Anyone has better ideas to use some regex???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930/how-can-i-determine-the-ip-of-my-router-gateway-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't rely on the format of the command always being the same (for example, if someone in a non-English speaking country uses your code, the names of the various values will be different - this may or may not be important to you).

You can retrieve the same information using the [java.net](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/retrieving.html) package. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221517/how-to-get-subnet-mask-using-java) might give you a useful example.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
  "[\\n\\r]\\s*IP\\s+Address[^\\d]+(\\d\\S+).*Mask[^\\d]+(\\d\\S+).*Gateway[^\\d]+(\\d\\S+)",
  Pattern.DOTALL);
```