# how to find the default gateway ip address in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, dns, ip, gateway

I want to find out the default Gateway of client and DNS in jsp. Is there anyway to do that .I have find out IP address but i want to know the default gateway or DNS also.
I have done following to find ip of client.

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
String getWay = request.getRemoteAddr() ;   // Gateway
out.println("<br/>IP Address:"+ipAddress+"<br/>");
out.println("<br/>Gateway:"+getWay+"<br/>");
```

Comment: You used; request.getRemoteAddr() method? What it prints?

Comment: Does this probably solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930/how-can-i-determine-the-ip-of-my-router-gateway-in-java

Comment: @Shivam it gives me ip of client

Comment: @FelixGerber i want to find out the client gateway using ip or anything else.

Comment: That'll be difficult... You can only get this information on the *client*. The code you included runs on the *server*. You have to create some code which runs on the *client*. But if this is standard web traffic, the client runs only a web browser, and your web browser will not run .jsp code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet and analyse the response:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig");
p.waitFor();

BufferedReader reader = 
     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";           
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the link below. Hope that answers your question:
http://ireasoning.com/articles/find_local_ip_address.htm

> The most reliable way is to use the route table. On windows, "route
>   print" command gives us something like:
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c route print")
>
> On linux, we can check the route table at /proc/net/route
>
> BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
>   FileReader("/proc/net/route"))

Comment: this is the way to find rout of my network default gateway right? but i want to find any vsisting ip or client gateway

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: Since you are able to get the IPAddress, you could use the 'host -t ns <client ip>' command to get the DNS details, if you are on Linux/UNIX OS.