# How to get Local Ip of access point/router in java SE

Tags: java, networking

How can I get info about local address of my LAN router? I don't want to get public inet address, but the internal subnet address. It is for most routers 192.168.1.0 or 192.168.1.1. I don't want to execute any shell commands, but to find this just by java API.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is already answered [Here] ([How can I determine the IP of my router/gateway in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930/how-can-i-determine-the-ip-of-my-router-gateway-in-java)). I hope, it will resolve you query.

Comment: Not really, it uses execution of shell command and parse it's result. I want to do it with API not by any 3rd party program.